A confusing backtrace indicates there is a recursive invoking which is not as expected
My program experiences crashes very rarely, occurring occasionally only when the STR is triggered(STR is to suspend the program and resume the program in QNX OS). The following backtrace is confusing as it indicates that qnx_slog2::log_output() is calling itself, which is not possible since the corresponding code is not a recursive function.
The backtrace below really confuses me.

The backtrace tells that qnx_slog2::log_output() calls itself which is not possilbe since the the corresponding code is not a recursion function.
The address of this is 0x2 when qnx_slog2::log_output is called the second time, which is not a valid address for the instance.

(gdb) bt
#0 0x0000003ae09b5cc0 in ?? ()
#1 0x0000001b5319cf64 in qnx_slog2::log_output (this=0x2, level=1， fmt=0x3ae09c9138 ，level=1)
   at /home/jhone/qnx_slog2.hpp:137
#2 0x0000001b5319cf64 in qnx_slog2::log_output (this=0x1b531e9048 <gnx slog2::get log()::slog2instance>, level=1, 
   fmt=0x2ec2c7fbd0 "[st_slog2] 0MS-E oms_result_sender.cpp:174 operator()() soa ges dynamic rect width:0, height:0, x:0，y", level=1) 
   at /home/jhone/qnx_slog2.hpp:137
#3 0x0000003aed61fcc in malloc_lock.constprop.4 ()
   from //home/jhone/publish/lib/libc.so.5
#4 0x6c757365725f736d in ??()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Here is the code qnx_slog2.hpp:line 128 to 149
void log_output(short level, const char* fmt, ...) {
    if (true == log_block(level)) {
        return;
    }
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lock_);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    switch (log_type_) {
        case LOG_TYPE_QNX:
            if ((fmt != nullptr) && (match_level(level) > 0) && (*fmt != '\0')) {   //line 137
                vslog2f(nullptr, log_id_, match_level(level), fmt, args);
            }
            break;
        case LOG_TYPE_PRINTF: {
            memset(print_buffer_, 0, sizeof(print_buffer_));
            vsnprintf(print_buffer_, sizeof(print_buffer_), fmt, args);
            log_print(level);
            break;
        }
    }
    va_end(args);
}

As per the offical document, the vslog2f is thread safe.
Thanks to @Retired Ninja's tip.
The slog2_set_default_buffer is called first when initialising the instance. Here is the corresponding code snippet:
class qnx_slog2 {
  private:
    short log_type_ = LOG_TYPE_QNX;
    short log_level_ = LOG_DEBUG;
    int log_page_num_ = 4;
    int log_id_ = 116;
    std::mutex lock_;
    char print_buffer_[1024] = {0};
    slog2_buffer_t buf = {0};
  public:
    bool init() {
        if (log_type_ != LOG_TYPE_QNX) {
            return true;
        }
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lock_);
        slog2_buffer_set_config_t config{};
        config.buffer_set_name = __progname;
        config.num_buffers = 1;                
        config.verbosity_level = SLOG2_DEBUG1; 
        config.buffer_config[0].buffer_name = LOG_TAG;
        config.buffer_config[0].num_pages =
            log_page_num_;  // one page 4KB
        if (0 == slog2_register(&config, &buf, SLOG2_DISCARD_NEWLINE)) {
            slog2_set_default_buffer(buf);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //omit not important code
}

Reply to the potential problem that the format specifier doesn't match the type of the argument.
It's not possible because all the log messages are generated by the fmt library which is widely used by spdlog and etc. In other word, as the backtrace indicates the input arguments for qnx_slog2::log_output are always: short level and followed by a const char*, and no more indeed. A simple code snippet below to make it easy to understand.
std::string log_msg = fmt::format(" soa ges dynamic rect width:{}, height:{}, x:{}，y:{}", width, height, loc_x, loc_y);
qnx_slog2::get_instance().log_output(log_level, log_msg.c_str());

Could somebody shed some light on how to solve this problem step by step? I really don't know what to do first.
Update the implementation
Thanks to all of you.
The project used spdlog first, and we are required to use slog2 which is provided by the QNX itself instead later. So all the log format use {} other than %d，%s alike.There is a lot work to do the replacement one by one.
So that's why we still use fmt as the format tool, and then pass the formated string to the metod of qnx_slog2::log_output.
I agree with Red.Wave, slogc is the better chioce for this condition. I modify the implementation of qnx_slog2::log_output and the macros who calls it as below.
NOTE: Since the offical document says that the slogc is thread-safe, so I don't use std::mutex in the implementation anymore.
    void qnx_slog2::log_output(short level, const std::string& str) {
        if (true == log_block(level)) {
            return;
        }

        if (str.empty()) {
            return;
        }

        slog2c(nullptr, log_id_, match_level(level), str.c_str());
    }

    void qnx_slog2::log_output(short level, const char* ptr) {
        if (true == log_block(level)) {
            return;
        }

        slog2c(nullptr, log_id_, match_level(level), ptr);
    }

#define LOG_COMMON(log_level, log_level_str, fmt_log, ...)                                         \
    do {                                                                                           \
        try {                                                                                      \
            auto fmt_str = fmt::format("[" LOG_TAG "] [" log_level_str "] {}:{} {}() " fmt_log,    \
                                       __BASEFILE__, __LINE__, __func__, ##__VA_ARGS__);           \
            qnx_slog2::get_log().log_output(log_level, fmt_str);                                   \
        } catch (std::exception & e) {                                                             \
            char internal_print_buffer[MAX_SIZE];                                                  \
            int len = snprintf(internal_print_buffer, MAX_SIZE,                                    \
                               "[\" LOG_TAG \"] [CRITICAL] %s:%d %s() format error", __BASEFILE__,    \
                               __LINE__, __func__);                                                \
            qnx_slog2::get_log().log_output(log_level, internal_print_buffer);                     \
        }                                                                                          \
    } while (0);

#define SERVICE_CRITICAL(fmt_log, ...) LOG_COMMON(LOG_CRITICAL, "SERVICE-C", fmt_log, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define SERVICE_ERROR(fmt_log, ...) LOG_COMMON(LOG_ERROR, "SERVICE-E", fmt_log, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define SERVICE_WARN(fmt_log, ...) LOG_COMMON(LOG_WARN, "SERVICE-W", fmt_log, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define SERVICE_DEBUG(fmt_log, ...) LOG_COMMON(LOG_DEBUG, "SERVICE-D", fmt_log, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define SERVICE_INFO(fmt_log, ...) LOG_COMMON(LOG_INFO, "SERVICE-I", fmt_log, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define SERVICE_TRACE(fmt_log, ...) LOG_COMMON(LOG_INFO, "SERVICE-T", fmt_log, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define ALG_CRITICAL(fmt_log, ...) LOG_COMMON(LOG_CRITICAL, "ALG-C", fmt_log, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define ALG_ERROR(fmt_log, ...) LOG_COMMON(LOG_ERROR, "ALG-E", fmt_log, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define ALG_WARN(fmt_log, ...) LOG_COMMON(LOG_WARN, "ALG-W", fmt_log, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define ALG_DEBUG(fmt_log, ...) LOG_COMMON(LOG_DEBUG, "ALG-D", fmt_log, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define ALG_INFO(fmt_log, ...) LOG_COMMON(LOG_INFO, "ALG-I", fmt_log, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define ALG_TRACE(fmt_log, ...) LOG_COMMON(LOG_INFO, "ALG-T", fmt_log, ##__VA_ARGS__)

//omit simliar macros

For the newly modified implementation(seen above),the program crashes at a much lower probability(about 1/(33×18) while it's about 1(2×20) before) when the STR is triggered. But the backtrace still looks odd, too.
#0  0x00000055f55b5afc in ?? ()
#1  0x0000004b6a42a9b8 in qnx_slog2::log_output (level=2, str=..., this=<optimized out>) at /mnt/nfs/qnx710/target/qnx7/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1520
#2  qnx_slog2::log_output (str=..., level=2, this=<optimized out>) at /home/jhone/qnx_slog2.hpp:103
#3  OMSResultSender::<lambda()>::operator()(void) const (__closure=<optimized out>) at /home/jhone/oms_result_sender.cpp:135
#4  0x0000004b6a42a9b8 in qnx_slog2::log_output (level=2, str=..., this=<optimized out>) at /mnt/nfs/qnx710/target/qnx7/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1520
#5  qnx_slog2::log_output (str=..., level=2, this=<optimized out>) at /home/jhone/qnx_slog2.hpp:103
#6  OMSResultSender::<lambda()>::operator()(void) const (__closure=<optimized out>) at /home/jhone/oms_result_sender.cpp:135
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Tips:
1.the program is built with  -g -O3 -DNDEBUG   -std=gnu++14. Why there is both -g and -O3? Since it's a release version and the -g option is added all the time no matter what the version is.
2. the backtrace looks like three functions have been repeated called twice(OMSResultSender::<lambda()>::operator()(void), qnx_slog2::log_output and then qnx_slog2::log_output again, repeat the said functions again).

Are you analyzing the core on the same machine on which it was produced? malloc_lock  is unlikely to be calling qnx_slog2::log_output either, so your stack is probably completely bogus.

@EmployedRussian The program is runing in the embeded board. The coredump is generated when it crashes. There is no GDB-alike tool could be run on the embeded board. The coredump has to be analyzed on the server which provides the cross-compilation toolchain.

Do you call slog2_set_default_buffer before this? Is that buffer big enough?

Hrm, last guess, but I'd check and make sure there aren't any cases where the format specifier doesn't match the type of the argument. It does look like it could be a messed up stack and maybe that could do it.

"The coredump has to be analyzed on the server which provides the cross-compilation toolchain." -- make sure the cross-libc.so.5 you are using actually matches (is bit-identical) the libc.so.5 on the target. If it doesn't, you are looking at "garbage" and the mismatch is the most frequent cause of that.

Side note : va_list args; shold really NOT be used anymore in C++.  The code you show is pure "C" not C++. In C++ this kind of code should have been replaced with variadic function templates.

@PepijnKramer I see, thank you for the reply. I think variadic function templates may not work here since the vslog2f() need va_list args as input argument. If I am wrong, please let me know.

I see elements of modern C++ in this code, which makes me wonder why C variadic functions are being used in this context.

@Red.Wave Because the these C functions are provided by an other vendor.

@John looks like the vendor's team is confused. This is a major design flaw. Closed source OS has lots of such flaws. Generally QNX API is much better than windows. But the code base has lots of problems, documentation has deficiency. I don't care who owns the code. Poor quality is poor quality.

I don't see how you dismiss the mismatch of format - as the result of fmt::format isn't guaranteed to be free of % as far as I know. In general you should use printf("%s", str) instead of printf(str); (and similarly in this case).

@HansOlsson Thanks for the good tip. As the example mentioned in the end of the question, the arguments passed to qnx_slog2::log_output() are always: short type(i.e. level) and followed by a const char*, and no more indeed(see the example in the end of the question for details).  And for what you care about, I searched all over my project, no '%' has ever been passed to fmt::format(). So it's impossible that there is a % in the output of fmt::format. If I am wrong, please let me know.

@Red.Wave we are dealing with RTOS here, everything you do should be deterministic. It's quite a beast where "best practices" are quite different from your dogma "don't use simplest, use safest". But I agree with Hans, with every standard C-format  function the string argument always should be a format string explicitly. working with empty valist isn't safe.

@Swift-FridayPie The dogma is to think that simple can not be safe. I have had my time with QNX. So, I know exactly I am talking about. I seek to get the zero-cost promise of C++, which means safe and simple at the same time. Usingstd::format and std::print  leads to compile-time mismatch detection and faster than printf runtime. There's a workaround to identify the format string at runtime that doesn't involve std::vformat, if needed.

@john The root cause of problem is -clearly - improper use of unsafe C string and printing functions. As a result, a buffer overflow bug is overwriting a return address or an indirect jump address - resulting in recursion. I suggest avoiding the qnx_slog2 class, and creating your own class around slog2 C API. This is not the 1st time I see a bug in QNX API. You can specifically use the fast slog2c function, combined with std::format_to_n to get maximum efficiency, avoiding nasty C variadic function problems.

@Red.Wave Thank you for the detailed explanation & advice. 1. I am limited use C++11 and part C++14 features due the compiler is little old whose version is V8.2.  The std::format_to_n is not  available. The project used spdlog first, and we are required to use slog2 which is provided by the QNX itself instead.So as the code seen in the question, that's why we still use fmt as the format tool, and then pass the formated string to the metod of qnx_slog2. 2. slog2c is used to log a constant string ,which seems bettern then vslog2f for the special usage in my scenario.

{fmt} is the reference implementation for std <format>. It must have the format_to_n or similar. It is the modern alternative to vsnprintf family. The task doesn't look as scary as you picture tough. You just need to encapsulate a std::array of slog2_buffer_t and provide good constructor and accessors. Next, create a Scott Meyer singleton of the above type and use it. qnx_slog2 smells fishy. Try to avoid it; The little you've provided, shows a lot of coupling with no separation of concerns. In short  qnx_slog2 looks terrible.

@Red.Wave provided they hace only C++11, the meant fmtlib, not {fmt}

@Swift-FridayPie they are not 2. Same library, same repo.

@Red.Wave Thank you for the guidance, I have modified the implementation which could be seen in the post.

So the qnx_slog2 is eventually your own code. I n thar case everything is in your hands. Then why macros, when you can use [variadic]templates?

@Red.Wave I think the macro is still needed because I need the tags(say [SERVICE-C],[ALG-E[ and etc which are seen in my question) to distinguish the log for different modules and log levels.

No. You just need variadic templates.

@Red.Wave You mean mannually passing [SERVICE-C],[ALG-E] and etc to the variadic function templates when writing every log message?Say, logger_ref.log(LOG_DEBUG,"[SERVICE-C]", int_loc_x, int_loc_y)?

What's wrong with template<typename...Ts> auto logServiceC(Ts&&... args){logWithTag("[Service-C]", std::forward<Ts>(args)...);}?

@John look at

You wrote:

Reply to the potential problem that the format specifier doesn't match the type of the argument.
It's not possible because all the log messages are generated by the
fmt library which is widely used by
spdlog and etc. In other word, as the backtrace indicates the
input arguments for qnx_slog2::log_output are always: short level
and followed by a const char*, and no more indeed. A simple code
snippet below to make it easy to understand.
std::string log_msg = fmt::format(
  " soa ges dynamic rect width:{}, height:{}，x:{}，y:{}",
  width, height, loc_x, loc_y
);
qnx_slog2::get_instance().log_output(log_level, log_msg.c_str());


That snippet actually shows that you 100% are misusing log_output! Now, this probably isn't your actual problem in this case; but consider what would happen if width were a string with the value "100%wrong".
const char *width = "100%wrong";
const char *height = "42";
int x = 3;
int y = 4;
std::string log_msg = fmt::format(
  "rect width:{}, height:{}，x:{}，y:{}",
  width, height, loc_x, loc_y
);
assert(log_msg == "rect width:100%wrong, height:42, x:3, y:4");
qnx_slog2::get_instance().log_output(log_level, log_msg.c_str());

Now log_output is receiving a format string log_msg.c_str() which contains the bogus format-specifier "%w" and no trailing arguments to format into it. That's undefined behavior and likely crash.
What you meant to write was:

std::string log_msg = fmt::format(
  " soa ges dynamic rect width:{}, height:{}，x:{}，y:{}",
  width, height, loc_x, loc_y
);
qnx_slog2::get_instance().log_output(log_level, "%s", log_msg.c_str());


Or simply cut out the middleman and write

qnx_slog2::get_instance().log_output(
  log_level,
  " soa ges dynamic rect width:%d, height:%d，x:%d，y:%d",
  width, height, loc_x, loc_y
);


which has the additional benefit of allowing the compiler to type-check the arguments for you. Every mainstream compiler understands printf-style format strings, especially if you mark log_output with __attribute__((printf(2,3))), and so it'll be able to tell you if you screwed up any format specifiers. However, it also has the major downside that printf format specifiers on their own can't handle std::string, std::pair, etc.; and that presumably you've already written all of your logging to use fmt::format's minilanguage instead of printf's minilanguage, so it would be a pain to rewrite all your logging format-strings at this point.
Or at least stop using vsnprintf from inside log_output. Since you always pass a single literal string, you can just make it:
void log_output(short level, const char* literal_message) {
    if (true == log_block(level)) {
        return;
    }
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lock_);
    switch (log_type_) {
        case LOG_TYPE_QNX:
            if ((literal_message != nullptr) && (match_level(level) > 0) && (*literal_message != '\0')) {   //line 137
                vslog2f(nullptr, log_id_, match_level(level), "%s", literal_message);
            }
            break;
        case LOG_TYPE_PRINTF: {
            snprintf(print_buffer_, sizeof(print_buffer_), "%s", literal_message);
            log_print(level);
            break;
        }
    }
}


As for homing in on the actual problem... I think you're right that the backtrace is garbage. The caller's frame looks right, and fmt= has a sane value. (Although it is oddly truncated — is this an artifact of the debugger, or is it really truncated in memory? Find out!) But the callee's frame has a null pointer for this and a plausible-looking-but-apparently-undebuggable value for fmt=.
#1 0x0000001b5319cf64 in qnx_slog2::log_output (this=0x2, level=1，
   fmt=0x3ae09c9138 ，level=1)
   at /home/jhone/qnx_slog2.hpp:137
#2 0x0000001b5319cf64 in qnx_slog2::log_output (this=0x1b531e9048 <gnx slog2::get log()::slog2instance>, level=1, 
   fmt=0x2ec2c7fbd0 "[st_slog2] 0MS-E oms_result_sender.cpp:174 operator()() soa ges dynamic rect width:0, height:0，x:0，y", level=1) 
   at /home/jhone/qnx_slog2.hpp:137

I assume that if 0x3ae09c9138 actually pointed at a string, the debugger would show you that string. (Find out what is at that address!) If it's just garbage, then that whole stack frame is probably junk and not helpful. But then that could mean that the crash happened while the program was in the process of building a new stack frame — after it had populated some of the next call's arguments but not all of them.
Could the call itself be crashing? Does log_output make any indirect calls through function pointers that could be pointing to garbage, or be null?
Can you step line by line in the debugger? Can you add "debugging printfs" to see exactly which lines are successfully executed before the crash?
(That Unicode fullwidth comma ， in the stack trace is also really suspicious; but it makes me suspect that you, not the debugger, edited out something there.)

Thank you for the detailed answer which helps me a lot 1. There is no warning when the fomat passed to the log_output is sth like std::string::c_str() other than "%s" alike even if  log_output
is marked with __attribute__(format(printf,x,y)). 2. The crash is at a very low probability(1/40) and no qdb(a gdb work with QNX OS) could work on the embeded board. So step line by line in the debugger is not possible. I try to add "debugging printfs" to see which lines are successfully executed before the crash and the value of 0x3ae09c9138.

3. Sorry, the Unicode fullwidth comma ， in the stack trace is my fault indeed, though I have carefully checked. 4. Could the call itself be crashing? Does log_output make any indirect calls through function pointers that could be pointing to garbage, or be null? In my opinion, as the implementation of log_output which has been shown in the question, it seems that the log_output only calls vslog2f and no other possible function. So what you said seems impossible. If I miss sth, please let me know.

@John: 1. "There is no warning..." Well, there is if you uncomment the line that gives the warning. No warning — Warning. To get warnings about non-literal format strings, turn on -Wformat=2 and/or -Wformat-nonliteral. (It's not part of -Wall, although I think it should be.)

The -Wformat=2 does not do any useful\actual ckecking indeed as the compiler clearly says  format not a string literal, argument types not checked.

@John: Right, that's why I wrote "Or simply cut out the middleman and write [...] which has the additional benefit of allowing the compiler to type-check the arguments for you." What you're doing now, which is buggy, is that you're format'ing your stuff into a string and then sprintf'ing that string into another string. I suggested that you stop format'ing, and just sprintf directly: qnx_slog2::get_instance().log_output(log_level, " soa ges dynamic rect width:%d, height:%d，x:%d，y:%d", width, height, loc_x, loc_y);.

I see. But it's a huge work. The project used spdlog first, then we are required to use the slog to control the size of the log by the system and make the export of log easier(with the log of other programs together).

I agree with you that the key problem is with the implemention of the logger. After I have modified it, it still crashes which is out of my expection. The backstrace still indicates that there is something wrong with the implemention of the logger. But good news is that the program crashes at a much lower probability(about 1/(33×18) much lower than 1/(2×20)) when the STR is triggered. The details could be seen in the question.

@John: To debug it, try reducing the test case by iteratively removing things and seeing whether the failure still reproduces. For example, what happens if you replace each s = fmt::format(...); use(s) with s = fmt::format(...); use("dummy string")? What happens if you replace each with use("dummy string") alone?

What about replace all the log by log_output(log_level, "dummy string");   first? If no crash ever occurs, it indicates the problem is with the implementation of logger. How do you think about it?  I must say sorry first. I forgot to tell you that the logger is used by three seprate processes. The OMS proccess crashes at low probability(1/(2x20)) while DMS is seldom seen for the original implementation of the logger. After the modification of the code, the DMS proccess has not been seen crashed while the OMS is much lower probability then before.The 3rd proccess seldom run.

I always ensure I have a C++ adapter layer between my C++ code and legacy "C" style coding (or any other language for that matter). This way I can ensure I will use all the latest C++ facilities for as long as I can.
#include <format>
#include <string_view>

// following two includes are only there to be able
// to simulate "C" style logging api
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


// legacy "C" style API for logging
void log_output_legacy(short level, const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, argList);
    va_end(argList);
}

// Your new variadic log formatting function
// making use of the std::vformat 
template<typename... args_t>
void log(short level, std::string_view fmt, args_t&&... args)
{
    auto message = std::vformat(fmt,std::make_format_args(args...));

    // use the formatted string
    log_output_legacy(level,"%i : %s", level, message.c_str());
}

// setup an abstract base class for reporting back to a log system
// Side note logging directly from your code is not recommended, make sure you can do something with dependency injection. 
// I call it reporting, because logging is just one possible implementation
class report_itf
{
public:
    virtual ~report_itf() = default;
    virtual void report_something_bad_happened() const noexcept = 0;
};

// for unit testing do not log at all
// to prevent tests becoming dependent on
// correct logging configuration etc. 
class no_reporting_t : public report_itf
{
public:
    virtual void report_something_bad_happened() const noexcept override {}
};

// for production code 
class legacy_reporting_t : public report_itf
{
public:
    virtual void report_something_bad_happened() const noexcept override 
    {
        log(2, "something bad happened\n");
    }
};


// when code needs to log, inject the report interface
class some_class_t
{
public:
    some_class_t( report_itf& reporting) : 
        m_reporting{reporting}
    {
    };

    void do_something()
    {
        m_reporting.report_something_bad_happened();
    }

private:
    const report_itf& m_reporting;

};


int main()
{
    log(1,"{} {} {}\n", "hello", "world!", 123);
    
    legacy_reporting_t reporting; // for unit test use no_reporting
    some_class_t some_class{reporting}; 

    some_class.do_something();
}


Thank you for the detailed code. Now I undertand your comment better. I still have two questions. 1. If I undstand you correctlly, class report_itf and its child classes are served to dependency injection pattern which you think it's better than directly call the template log() functon. What're the binifits? To make the code easier to modify  in case the low-level logger needs to be changed in the future? 2. report_itf is short for report_interface? Sorry of my poor English. :(

No worries about your poor english it is good enough :)  The benefits of dependency injection are that you can indeed later replace your logging system for a completely different one (even if things like severity change). But as I've shown it also helps with unit testing e.g. a lot of log systems need open databases or open files... all of which can fail and you don't want your (unit) tests to depend on that.  And yes itf is my shorthand for interface (in C++ also called a pure abstract baseclass). If you've more questions let me know :)

It seems that you are utilizing the dependency injection pattern, which is indeed a good practice. However, I am encountering an issue where every class that needs to use the logger must be passed the reference or pointer of the logger (e.g. Foo(..., Logger&) or Foo::set_logger(Logger*)). This is quite labor-intensive. How do you think about it?

It's commonly the price you have to pay for dependency injection. So in the end it is one of those engineering choices. Will your project stay small then you could use a meyer's singleton to return you a reference to an abstract logger (interface) which you can replace in test code. Or if you're project is going to be big and long-living... just pay the dependency injection up front (it will make refactoring/unit testing more easy later)
